# What is the best way to change currency in wordpress woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The default currency in the template based n woocomeerce that I am using is British pounds. The currency in the target country is different. Based on searching I found few ways of changing the currency. What is the best way?

http://www.kriesi.at/support/topic/change-of-the-woocommerce-price-currency

http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/snippets/add-a-custom-currency-symbol/

Furthermore, in which `function.php` file should the code be included? (one within `wootemplate` folder or within `wp-includes` directory)

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution to this?

Comment: No, got the solution long back. I've posted it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any of the link mentioned in the above question. Add the code to functions.php of the theme. If using child theme, add it to the functions.php of child.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check this code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
function change_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
switch( $currency ) {
case 'AUD': $currency_symbol = 'AUD $'; break;
}
return $currency_symbol;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want multi currency on your shop then try wordpress plugins for this functionality. but you must need to change settings from the woo-commerce end for checkout page & shipping cost calculation. plugins will switch currency at the shop but only few of them can able manage the same currency at cart & checkout page & while shipping cost calculation.